# Show that $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b)|a,b\in\mathcal{Q}\}$ is a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b)|a,b\in\mathcal{Q}\}$ is a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}$.

Proof: Let $x\in \mathbf{R}$. Notice that < is an order relation on $\mathbf{R}$ and that $a<b$. Then we must have $a<x<b$, for some $x\in\mathbf{R}$. Therefore, $x\in(a,b)\in\mathcal{B}$. Now, suppose $x\in\mathbf{B_{1}}\cap\mathbf{B_{2}}$, $\mathbf{B_{1}},\mathbf{B_{2}}\in\mathcal{B}$,i.e., $x\in(a,b)\cap(c,d)$, respectively, with $a<b$ and $c<d$. Since $\mathbf{B_{1}}\cap\mathbf{B_{2}}$ is nonempty, we must have that $c<b$. Then, either $x\in(a,c)\subset(a,b)$ or $x\in(c,b)\subset(a,b)$, since $(a,c)\cup(c,b)=(a,b)$ (A similar argument shows that x could also be in $(c,b)$ or $(b,d)$, since $(c,b)\cup(b,d)=(c,d)$). Hence, $\mathcal{B}$ forms a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}$.

How did I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you might want to be a bit more careful about a few particular details.

First, you need to verify that each element of $\mathcal{B}$ is indeed contained in the standard topology. This guarantees that the standard topology is finer than the topology induced by $\mathcal{B}$. Taking the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ to be the order topology with basis elements $(a, b)$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, then it is easy to see that for any $(q, r) \in \mathcal{B}$, that $q, r \in \mathbb{Q} \implies q, r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, to show that the topology induced by $\mathcal{B}$ is finer than the standard topology, consider an arbitrary basis element $(a, b)$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, of the order topology; consider $x \in (a, b)$. Now, we use the fact (proof is relatively straightforward and shall not be produced here) that for any $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_1 < q < x_2$. Then, since $a < x$, there exists $q_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a < q_1 < x$, and since $x < b$, there exists $q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < q_2 < b$. Then $(q_1, q_2) \in \mathcal{B}$ contains $x$ and is contained in $(a, b)$. Since all of $x, a, b$ were arbitrary, the topology induced by $\mathcal{B}$ is indeed finer than the standard topology.